# String interpolation of an object is not working because of the initialisation in TS

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, string-interpolation

I am creating a simple application which for now only has two pages:

(1) A full list of stocks.
(2) Details about a single stock.

When you click on a specific stock in the list of stocks, you should be routed to the other page to read its info.

Here is the service I use:

```
export class StockService {

  stock$ = new Subject();

  public setStock(stock: Stock){
    this.stock$.next(stock);
  }

  public getStock():Observable<any>{
    return this.stock$.asObservable();
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

On my page (1) I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">


<app-stock-object
*ngFor="let stock of stocks"
[stock] = "stock"
(click)="setSelected(stock)"
routerLink="/stock-details">

</app-stock-object>

</div>
```

And the following class in TS

```
  export class StocksComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() stocks: Stock[] = Stock_data;
  constructor(private stockService: StockService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public setSelected(stock: Stock){
    this.stockService.setStock(stock);
  }

}
```

The second page where I (try to) retrieve the stock:

```
export class StockDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

//Initilialising without a value ...
  stock: any;
  constructor(private stockService: StockService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.stockService.getStock().subscribe(stock=>{
//The message below is shown with the selected stock.
    console.log("stock -->",stock);
    this.stock = stock;
  })
}

}
```

and the HTML:

```
<p>the stock details are: {{stock?.name}}</p>
```

I think that it is because I initialise the stock without a value to declare its type. I am new to Angular and am therefore having issues seeing what the best solution would be to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: does StockDetailsComponent  uses OnPush Change detection strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject as Behavior Subject will give you last emitted value even if you subscribe in future. For eg :-

```
stock$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Comment: Thank you. What should I replace 'null' with?

Comment: null is fine here as default value of stock is null till stock is available. in the bracket we provide the default value.

Comment: I see, it failed to compile since I had assigned it a custom type, and it was not assignable to parameter of type null. It works now :)

Comment: if it works, can you please mark it as answer.